# How to parse a JSON object into a custom object using Gson?

Tags: android, gson

I have the following JSON object as a String:

```
[{"Add1":"101","Description":null,"ID":1,"Name":"Bundesverfassung","Short":"BV"},{"Add1":"220","Description":null,"ID":2,"Name":"Obligationenrecht","Short":"OR"},{"Add1":"210","Description":null,"ID":3,"Name":"Schweizerisches Zivilgesetzbuch","Short":"ZGB"},{"Add1":"311_0","Description":null,"ID":4,"Name":"Schweizerisches Strafgesetzbuch","Short":null}]
```

Now i created a class that represents one of the results:

```
public class Book {

    private int number;
    private String description;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String abbrevation;

    public Book(int number, String description, int id, String name, String abbrevation) {
        this.number = number;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.abbrevation = abbrevation;
    }

}
```

Now I want to use [Gson](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/) to parse the JSON object into a list of Book objects. I tried it this way, but obviously it doesn't work. How can I fix that?

```
public static Book[] fromJSONtoBook(String response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.fromJson(response, Book[].class);
    }
```

Comment: All of my variables in the book class ar null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, you have to use the annotation `SerializedName` to indicated which part of the JSON object is used to parse the JSON object to a Book object:

```
public class Book {

    @SerializedName("Add1")
    private String number;

    @SerializedName("Description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Short")
    private String abbrevation;

    public Book(String number, String description, int id, String name, String abbrevation) {
        this.number = number;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.abbrevation = abbrevation;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is my preferred approach when using Jackson.  I figured Gson had it, but I didn't know what it was off the top of my head.  +1 for another excellent implementation.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException how do I SerializedName an inner JSON object. I was trying, `@SerializedName("activity.id")` to refer an 'id' key inside a 'activity' object which is inside another JSON object, but it was returning null. However, siblings of the 'activity' object in the outer JSON object are just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that GSON knows how to map your JSONArray of JSONObjects to your Book class.  I have a couple observations about this setup.

- If you notice, the JSONObjects which
  make up the JSONArray contain the
  properties "Add1" and "Short", but
  your Book class does not have
  properties that have the same names.
- The types should be noted.  I am
  guessing that "Add1" is going to map
  to the number property (purely a
  guess), and the type is String in the
  JSONObject, but it is an int in the
  Book class.
- I am wondering whether the case of
  the Book class properties need to
  match the case of the JSONObject.
- Your Book class does not contain a
  public default constructor, which I
  think GSON needs to map.

The above are just a couple suggestions I have, which are not necessarily correct or complete as I have not used GSON before.